# Error DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver , concept of forwarding in Spring Boot, status=405

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new in concept of forwarding with spring boot and Thymeleaf.
I want to use forwarding in my application from one Controller to another getting sessionAttribute.

I have a placed a form in /home page and when I click on submit button, the for gets submitted to database but the application does not render the next (service.html) page using redirect.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class SavingUser{

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;



@GetMapping("/home")
public String addUser(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("user", new Customer());
    return "index";
}

@PostMapping("/registerUser")
public Callable <String> userRegistration(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") Customer user, BindingResult result, Model model, HttpServletRequest request){
 ---
 ----
    return()->{
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
         ---
     }
        ----
        return "redirect:/greetingCustomer";
    };
}
```

Forwarding to another controller -

```
@Controller
 public class GreetingService {

@PostMapping("/greetingCustomer")
public String greetCustomer(@SessionAttribute("user")Customer customer, Model model) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("A new user " + customer.getName() + " is trying to request a quote");
    model.addAttribute("person",customer.getName());
    return "redirect:/service";
 }
}
```

I already have placed the 'service.html' file in classpath.
I used this same concept with JSP and it worked well.
Any idea what the problem is ?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see when you are using `return "redirect:/greetingCustomer";` then you can only redirect to the greetingCustomer.
If you want to redirect to the service page the use `return "redirect:/service";`